# webelement is not subscriptable on click of Linkedin feed posts using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve LinkedIn live feed posts and click on each posted page(in order to retrieve the page details like last one week's post).

My code is

```
for i in range(0,5)
    poster_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class,'update-components-actor__title')]")[i].text
    posts_text = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'update-components-text relative feed-shared-update-v2__commentary')]/span")[i].text
```

from the above code, I can retieve feed post name, posted text. When I try to click on the respective post

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'update-components-actor')]/a").click()
```

I am getting errors like

```
webelement is not subscriptable
```

So the complete idea is I will create the table to display feed posts in my Python HTML. after that, each poster on a click of the table will show poster information for the past 7 days.
Someone help me retrieve those details on click of the poster and fix this issue. Let me know what mistakes have made.